# Why Transfer function doesn't check for allowance comparing to TransferFrom?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, openzeppelin-contracts, transfer, allowance

1. Why `Transfer` function doesn't check for allowance comparing to `TransferFrom`?
2. Do I need to call `increaseAllowance` each time before calling `TransferFrom`?

Ex implementation of Transfer without allowance check

```
    function transfer(address receiver, uint256 numTokens) public override returns (bool) {
        require(numTokens <= balances[msg.sender]);
        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(numTokens);
        balances[receiver] = balances[receiver].add(numTokens);
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, receiver, numTokens);
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Using account `A` in order to execute `transferFrom(source, target, amount)` requires both:

   - `source` holds at least `amount` of the given token
   - `A` has been approved by `source` to transfer from it at least `amount` of the given token
2. Using account `A` in order to execute `transfer(target, amount)` requires only:

   - `A` holds at least `amount` of the given token
3. Your question is essentially, why doesn't it also require:

   - `A` has been approved by `A` to transfer from it at least `amount` of the given token?
4. And the answer is obviously:

   - Because it is pointless to approve yourself to do something (anything really)

---

This is true regardless of whether `A` is an externally-owned account or a smart-contract account.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, ```transferFrom``` is called from another contract and 
instead of calling ```a.approve(sender, amount)``` I need to call ```sender.approve(a, amount)```

Comment: @DmitryDyachkov: Precisely. And with `sender` typically being an externally-owned account, `sender.approve` needs to be executed from the off-chain (e.g., in a web3.js script).

Comment: Adding onto #4 – even if you own the tokens, if you call `transferFrom` without explicitly approving yourself first, the transaction will fail and revert. It is always better to use `transfer` in this case.